# Is scanf's "regex" support a standard?

Tags: c, gcc, scanf

Is scanf's "regex" support a standard? I can't find the answer anywhere.

This code works in gcc but not in Visual Studio:

```
scanf("%[^\n]",a);
```

It is a Visual Studio fault or a gcc extension ?

EDIT: Looks like VS works, but have to consider the difference in line ends between Linux and Windows.(\r\n)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out a feature I never knew existed; do note though that `scanf(3)` and friends are _library functions_, and not provided by `gcc` but rather by the C library (typically `glibc` on Linux systems, but there are several C libraries available).

Comment: What do you mean `scanf("%[^\n]",a);` doesn't work in Visual Studio?  It works for me. Post more code (specifically what's `a`), input, output, and expected output.

Comment: Michael, sure the code compile. But it does not behave like the Linux version. My code keeps jumping with a \r\n in the buffer. I will change the filter to \r\n to check later. Thanks !

Comment: This is a great quiz question for deep C library knowledge.

Comment: The problem seems to be that you're reading a text file in **binary mode**. In C in strings there should be only `\n` as line terminators.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That particular format string *should* work fine in a conforming implementation. The `[` character introduces a scanset for matching a non-empty set of characters (with the `^` meaning that the scanset is an inversion of the characters supplied). In other words, the format specifier `%[^\n]` should match every character that's not a newline.

From C99 7.19.6.2, slightly paraphrased:

> The `[` format specifier matches a nonempty sequence of characters from a set of expected characters (the scanset). If no `l` length modifier is present, the corresponding argument shall be a pointer to the initial element of a character array large enough to accept the sequence and a terminating null character, which will be added automatically.
>
> If an `l` length modifier is present, the input shall be a sequence of multibyte characters that begins in the initial shift state. Each multibyte character is converted to a wide character as if by a call to the `mbrtowc` function, with the conversion state described by an `mbstate_t` object initialized to zero
>   before the first multibyte character is converted. The corresponding argument shall be a pointer to the initial element of an array of `wchar_t` large enough to accept the sequence and the terminating null wide character, which will be added automatically.
>
> The conversion specifier includes all subsequent characters in the format string, up to and including the matching right bracket `]`. The characters between the brackets (the scanlist) compose the scanset, unless the character after the left bracket is a circumflex `^`, in which case the scanset contains all
>   characters that do not appear in the scanlist between the circumflex and the right bracket. If the conversion specifier begins with `[]` or `[^]`, the right bracket character is in the scanlist and the next following right bracket character is the matching right bracket that ends the specification; otherwise the first following right bracket character is the one that ends the specification. If a `-` character is in the scanlist and is not the first, nor the second where the first character is a `^`, nor the last  character, the behavior is implementation-defined.

It's possible, if MSVC isn't working correctly, that this is just one of the many examples where Microsoft either don't conform to the latest standard, or think they know better :-)

Comment: I believe the non conforming part can be the way `a` got its content. If you open a text file in binary mode and try to process the lines, **you** have to translate the line endings yourself.

Comment: The scanset support `"%[...]"` was in `scanf()` in 7th Edition UNIX™ in 1979.  It is at least a decade older than any C standard.

Answer (score 6):

The `"%["` format spec for `scanf()` is standard and has been since C90.

MSVC does support it.

You can also provide a field width in the format spec to provide safety against buffer overruns:

```
int main()
{
    char buf[9];

    scanf("%8[^\n]",buf);

    printf("%s\n", buf);
    printf("strlen(buf) == %u\n", strlen(buf));

    return 0;
}
```

Also note that the `"%["` format spec doesn't mean that `scanf()` supports regular expressions.  That particular format spec is similar to a capability of regexs (and no doubt was an influenced by regex), but it's far more limited than regular expressions.

Comment: Note: `scanf("%8[^\n]",buf);` does not read anything if input is `"\n"`.  `buf` is left uninitialized.